# Importing from __init__.py within a file

Tags: python

I have a file structure that looks like this:

- pckg/

  - __ init __.py
  - module1
  - module2
  - module3
  - module4

In the `__init__.py` I import all of the classes from the modules, so they are available on 'from pckg import (class)' However, I can't seem to use this method within the modules.

For example, in module1 I have to import the classes I need from module2 and module 3, I can't directly import them from pckg. Is this the expected result when trying to import from within a package, or am I doing something wrong? Let me know if more info would be helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Circular (or cyclic) imports in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python)

Comment: You might want to have a look at the discussion in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected result, because I am doing a circular import without realizing it!

Thanks to a comment from Iguananaut I realized this is an example/special case of the Circular imports in Python, which is addressed elsewhere.